# DebugView DeviceId Error

Tags: debugging, device, debugview

When I run DbgView.exe I am getting the following output. I tried "Run as Administrator" but no change. 
[image: DbgView Output]

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to DebugView but because one of the loaded drivers or an internal Windows component produces this output.

Likely Device Monitor is an internal Windows component. You may have a non-functional device on your system. You may follow the followind link to troubleshoot the problem : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314464/en-us